# Facebook create page through the FB JS API

Tags: javascript, api, facebook

I've not found a way to create a FB page through the FB JS API in FB docs or Google, somebody knows how to create a new page (a business, artist, etc.) through the FB JS API?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook does not support creating pages, profiles, groups, etc. through any of their APIs. The only way to do this is on facebook.com.